# R ggplot with 2 y-axes at different scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following is df_sales

```
df_sales <- structure(list(Year_of_Release = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004,  2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015,  2016), Sales_Sum = c(201.58, 331.47, 395.51, 357.8, 419.05, 458.31,  518.22, 605.37, 671.79, 658.88, 590.59, 507.79, 355.84, 361.24,  331.51, 268.05, 130.1), Sales_Avg = c(0.576, 0.688, 0.477, 0.462,  0.55, 0.488, 0.515, 0.506, 0.471, 0.462, 0.471, 0.447, 0.545,  0.664, 0.571, 0.442, 0.259)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ), row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

The following are the codes for plotting

```
> ggplot(data = df_sales, aes(x = Year_of_Release)) +   geom_line(aes(y
> = Sales_Avg, colour = "Sales (Avg)")) +   geom_line(aes(y = Sales_Sum, colour = "Sales (Sum)")) +   scale_y_continuous(name = 'Sales (Avg)',
>                      sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ ., name = "Sales (Sum)")) +   labs(y = "Sales (Sum)",
>        x = "Year of release",
>        colour = "")
```

However, the resulting plot looks weird. One geom_line was not added properly.

[image]

Comment: There are many worked examples on So. Do some searching. And images of data are severely deprecated on SO

Comment: To be more specific, could you please enter your data in a more user-friendly way (e.g. with `dput()` or as a text block)? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example .  I think your problem is that `sec_axis` doesn't autoscale - you have to provide an appropriate transformation, e.g. `trans = ~ . *1000)`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it looks sec_axis does not work. I tried with example codes, which are working but just not working for this specific data. Please see `dput` codes for `df_sales` as follows.

Comment: `structure(list(Year_of_Release = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016), Sales_Sum = c(201.58, 331.47, 395.51, 357.8, 419.05, 458.31, 
518.22, 605.37, 671.79, 658.88, 590.59, 507.79, 355.84, 361.24, 
331.51, 268.05, 130.1), Sales_Avg = c(0.576, 0.688, 0.477, 0.462, 
0.55, 0.488, 0.515, 0.506, 0.471, 0.462, 0.471, 0.447, 0.545, 
0.664, 0.571, 0.442, 0.259)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -17L))`